# SQL Update - Multiple Rows and Multiple Critieria in one SQL Statement

Tags: sql, case, case-when

I am trying to update two fields based on two different criteria and I cannot figure out how to accomplish this in a single SQL statement.

Is this possible without a loop?

Here are single-row examples of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
Update Leadtimes Set Leadtime = 10 Where supplier = 123 and location = 1;
Update Leadtimes Set Transit_Leadtime = 5 Where supplier = 123 and location = 1;
Update Leadtimes Set Leadtime = 12 Where supplier = 123 and location = 2;
Update Leadtimes Set Transit_Leadtime = 6 Where supplier = 123 and location = 2;
Update Leadtimes Set Leadtime = 5 Where supplier = 223 and location = 1;
Update Leadtimes Set Transit_Leadtime = 3 Where supplier = 223 and location = 1;
Update Leadtimes Set Leadtime = 7 Where supplier = 223 and location = 2;
Update Leadtimes Set Transit_Leadtime = 2 Where supplier = 223 and location = 2;
```

This is the statement I found online that I haven't been successful in modifying to do the job.

```
UPDATE categories
    SET display_order = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 3
        WHEN 2 THEN 4
        WHEN 3 THEN 5
    END,
    title = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 'New Title 1'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'New Title 2'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'New Title 3'
    END
WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? I guess it is MS SQL server, am I right?

Comment: at some point you spend more time trying to come up with a clever query that you might as well just have executed multiple simpler queries to begin with...

Answer (score 1):

```
Update Leadtimes 
    Set 
        Leadtime = CASE CAST(supplier AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(location AS VARCHAR(MAX))
            WHEN '1231' THEN 10
            WHEN '1232' THEN 12
            WHEN '2231' THEN 5
            WHEN '2232' THEN 7
        END,
        Transit_Leadtime = CASE CAST(supplier AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(location AS VARCHAR(MAX))
            WHEN '1231' THEN 5
            WHEN '1232' THEN 6
            WHEN '2231' THEN 3
            WHEN '2232' THEN 2
        END 
Where supplier in (123, 223) and location in (1, 2);
```

Here are the results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Update Leadtimes Set Leadtime = 10 Where supplier = 123 and location = 1;
Update Leadtimes Set Transit_Leadtime = 5 Where supplier = 123 and location = 1;
```

Could be written as:

```
UPDATE Leadtimes SET Leadtime = 10, Transit_Leadtime = 5 WHERE supplier = 123 AND location = 1;
```

I would prepare a statement of the form :

```
UPDATE Leadtimes SET Leadtime = ?, Transit_Leadtime = ? WHERE supplier = ? AND location = ?;
```

And then execute it for all the data quads I'd need.